# Convert Python to PHP - GCP Authorisation Credentials

Tags: php, python, google-cloud-platform

I am using GCP Cloud Vision API with Python to retrieve some information from images. Specifically, I am sending a photo of a product to this API and I retrieve the web entities related to it; one of them is almost always the brand.

My basic Python script that does this job is the following:

```
import  io
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Project_name.json"

def detect_text(file):

    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    with io.open(file, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = types.Image(content=content)
    web_detection = client.web_detection(image=image).web_detection
    print(web_detection)

file_name = "/Users/User/Desktop/Image.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(file_name)
detect_text(file_name)
```

The `Project_name.json` file contains some authorisation credentials so that I can have access to the Google Cloud API Client.

I want to do the same thing with PHP. For this reason I have written the the following PHP script so far:

```
<?php

namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Vision;
use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;

function detect_web($path)
{
    $imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();

    $image = file_get_contents($path);
    $response = $imageAnnotator->webDetection($image);
    $web = $response->getWebDetection();

    print($web);
}

$path = '/Users/User/Desktop/Image.jpg';
detect_web($path);

?>
```

But when I run this I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php:12 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php(26): Google\Cloud\Samples\Vision\detect_web('/Users/User...') #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 12
```

Obviously, this error appears because (first of all) I have not provided the Google Authorisation Credentials as I did in Python above (`os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Project_name.json"`).

What should I do to get the appropriate Google library and access it through my PHP script to get the exact same result as in my Python script?

Comment: did you require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'? If not you need to, or manually require in each class you will use

Comment: where is your 'vendor/autoload.php' file. First import them then try again.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Hm, I have never used or even touched  any `vendor/autoload.php` so I have no clue what I should with this.

Comment: how did you get the google lib? download, or through composer?

Comment: To be precise, I have done nothing more than writing this php script. So I did not get any google lib with composer or anything. In a sense, this is exactly the question from my post: What should I do to get the library and access it through my php script? In other words, what files should I modify (and how) to get the right Google lib and what to write in my php script to access this?

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth#using_a_service_account) and select JSON as key type for authenticating yo Cloud Vision API. The steps to setting up authentication is provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#setting_up_authentication). Once you have the JSON key file, you can setup the environment variable using the ‘export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS’ command pointing to the JSON key file. You can use the [PHP version](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#client-libraries-usage-php) of the client library for the Cloud Vision API. Also here is the [PHP API Reference documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.67.0/vision/visionclient) for additional help.